# Overwrite a string from the middle

Tags: vb.net, str-replace

I am trying to make a function to create textboxes. I need to know if there is a way to replace the end of a string with the new number.

```
While x <= tbnumberofitems
        Dim x As Integer = 0 ' looop count '
    Dim y As Integer = 1 ' name count'
    Dim label1name As String = "label"
    Dim textbox1name As String = "textbox"
    While x <= tbnumberofitems
        y = y + 1
        If x = 0 Then y = 1

        Convert.ToString(y)

        Dim label1 As New Label
        label1.Name = label1name & y

        'Code to create label box

        Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
        textbox1.Name = textbox1name & y

        'code to create text box

        x = x + 1


    End While
```

This is what I currently have. What I need now is a way to make it where when the loop runs the next time, it changes the name to textbox2 and label2 on 3rd loop label 3 and textbox 3, etc. If that is not clear enough what I am trying to do is make it where the numberofitems, make it 5, creates 5 labels and 5 textboxes through the program.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly Like this ..

```
For x as Integer = 1 to tbnumberofitems

    'Code to create label
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Name = "label" & format(x)
    lbl.Location = New Point(10, x*20)
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

    'Code to create textbox
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Name = "TextBox" & format(x)
    tb.Location = New Point(100, x*20)
    Me.Controls.Add(tb)

Next
```

Comment: Right. I dont need the code to add the textbox. I need the code to add x textboxes.

Comment: ive never used the format command. format makes it named tb2 within the program if x = 2?

Comment: doesnt that just change the name of the textbox though? I need to create x number of textboxes.

Comment: @CalvinSmith : This code is only sample about how to create control with name from your iteration .. you have to do the rest ..